# Finding the probability function of the maximal number

Tags: probability, proof-verification

$n$ balls in a jug numbered $1,\dots,n$. pulling out a ball $m$ times with return. Let $X$ be the maximal number that we got in the $m$ pullings.

> Find the probability function of $X$ (HINT:first calculate the probability that $X$ will be not bigger from some $k$)

---

**My attempt:**

Let's use the hint $P(X\leq k)=$

let's begin with $k=1$ so that means that the maximal number that I pulled out in $m$ trials is one the probaility to pull out the ball that numbered by one is $1/n$, but I want to pull the ball $m$ times so

$P(X=1)=(1/n)^m$

Now, for $k=2$ that means that the maximal number that I pulled out in $m$ trials is two in each trial I can pull out or the ball that numbered by one or the ball that numberd by two therefore:

$P(X=2)=(2/n)^m$

$\bullet$

$\bullet$

$\bullet$

$P(X=n)=(n/n)^m$

> I know that I'm wrong,  because $P(X=n)=1$ but I don't know *where* am I wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k=0$ to $n$, we have 
$$\Pr(X\le k)=(k/n)^m.$$
For the maximum is $\le k$ precisely if on each of the $m$ trials we pull a ball with number $\le k$.

To finish, note that 
$$\Pr(X=k)=\Pr(X\le k)-\Pr(X\le k-1).$$

Answer (score 1):

If you change each of your $P(X=k)$ to $P(X\le k)$, then your equations will be correct. Then, $P(X=k)$ can be found by:
$$
P(X=k)=P(X\le k)-P(X\le k-1)
$$
Your original calculations neglect that for $P(X=2)$, you might pull the 1-ball m-times.